# How to run deployed R Code from SQL server 2016

Tags: sql, sql-server, r, sql-server-2016

How can i run an `R Code` which is deployed in `Microsoft R Server` using `sp_execute_external_script`.

I have an R Script, which is pretty lengthy. Now i want to deploy that script to R Server, so that any one with privileges can access that script. Also i want to execute that script from an SQL Server Stored Procedure by referring the script that is deployed in R Server.

Is it possible to do that ?

Comment: I have an R Script, which is pretty lengthy. Now i want to deploy that script to R Server, so that any one with privileges can access that script. Also i want to execute that script from an SQL Server Stored Procedure by referring the script that is deployed in R Server.

Answer (score 1):

tl;dr yes, you can.

I would recommend starting with this introduction from Microsoft:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt604885.aspx

When you understand it (and have set up a SQL Server 2016 correctly) the following tutorials can be helpful: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt591993.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can

**Note:** To run R code in Transact-SQL, you must be connected to an instance of SQL Server 2016 where SQL Server R Services is already installed .

**Exemple:**

```
exec sp_execute_external_script  @language =N'R',    
@script=N'OutputDataSet<-InputDataSet',      
@input_data_1 =N'select 1 as hello'    
with result sets (([hello] int not null));    
go
```

Good Lock